# When string will be output with double quotes?and when with single quotes?by %r

Tags: python

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"  
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "so I said goodnight."
)
```

Answer (score 4):

`str.__repr__` prefers single quotes, unless the string contains a single quote and no double quotes, in which case it uses double quotes.

Comment: And if it contains both it reverts to single quotes, and backslash-escapes any single quotes : `\'`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: *“… and no double quotes”*

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, just augmenting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `format()` function, don't care `%r`,single,double,triple quotes.

```
formatter= "{} {} {} {}"
print ((formatter).format (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "so I said goodnight."))
```

Output:

```
    >>>
    I had this thing. That you could type up right. But it didn't sing. so I said goodnight.
    >>>
```